# Test two different npm package versions at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, testing, npm

When I create an npm package, sometimes it would face the need to backward old dependency package version.

If the new version has new api, I may write the code in this pattern:

```
import pkg from 'some-pkg';
const isNewVersion = pkg.newVersionApi !== 'undefined';

if (isNewversion) {
  pkg.newVersionApi();
} else {
  pkg.oldVersionApi(); // backward compatible api
}
```

And with this pattern, when I want to write the test, I only can test the `installed version` code. The other version's code can't be tested.

For real example, in React v15 and v16, React v16 has new API [Portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). Before Portal release, v15 has `unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer` api to realize similar feature.

So the code for React would be like:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const isV16 = ReactDOM.createPortal !== 'undefined';

if (isV16) {
  ReactDOM.createPortal(...);
} else {
  ReactDOM.unstable_renderSubtreeIntoContainer(...);
}
```

So I want to ask is there any method to test with `different dependency version`?

Currently, one method I think of is to install the other version again and test it. But it only can do on local. It can't work on ci and it can't count in coverage together.

I think that is not only for react test. It may face on node.js test. Any suggestion can be discussed.

**Updated**

This question maybe is related to install `two versions dependency` in npm. But I know currently installing two versions dependency is not workable.

Comment: K.I.S.S. Principle: The quickest (and least technical) solution here would be to use two separate copies of your app, each with the different package versions you'd want to test.  This is trivial to do with `git`, since you can either 1) clone your app twice or 2) use two separate branches.

Comment: That's right. Using separate branch is one way. But if this is an open source or a co-working project. It's hard to control the merge branch problem. Because we need to tell the contributors to follow the test roadmap like update your change on both branch and test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a might be solution, not sure it will work as you expect. But, you will have a direction to move forward.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "express-demo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.3",
    "express": "~4.15.2",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.8.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "customDependecies": {
    "body-parser": [
      "",
      "1.18.1",
      "1.18.0"
    ]
  }
}
```

Note in above `package.json` file, I have added a new key `customDependecies` which I will use for installing multiple dependencies. Here I am using `body-parser` package for demo. Next you need file, that can read this `key` and install the deps.

**install-deps.js**

```
const {spawnSync} = require('child_process');
const fs = require('fs');

const customDependencies = require('./package.json').customDependecies;

spawnSync('mkdir', ['./node_modules/.tmp']);

for (var dependency in customDependencies) {
  customDependencies[dependency].forEach((version) => {
    console.log(`Installing ${dependency}@${version}`);
    if (version) {
      spawnSync('npm', ['install', `${dependency}@${version}`]);
      spawnSync('mv', [`./node_modules/${dependency}`, `./node_modules/.tmp/${dependency}@${version}`]);
    } else {
      spawnSync('npm', ['install', `${dependency}`]);
      spawnSync('mv', [`./node_modules/${dependency}`, `./node_modules/.tmp/${dependency}`]);
    }
  });

  customDependencies[dependency].forEach((version) => {
    console.log(`Moving ${dependency}@${version}`);
    if (version) {
      spawnSync('mv', [`./node_modules/.tmp/${dependency}@${version}`, `./node_modules/${dependency}@${version}`]);
    } else {
      spawnSync('mv', [`./node_modules/.tmp/${dependency}`, `./node_modules/${dependency}`]);
    }
  });
}
spawnSync('rm', ['-rf', './node_modules/.tmp']);
console.log(`Installing Deps finished.`);
```

Here, I am installing deps one by one in `tmp` folder and once installed, I am moving them to `./node_modules` folder.

Once, everything is installed, you can check the versions like below

**index.js**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser/package.json');
var bodyParser1181 = require('body-parser@1.18.1/package.json');
var bodyParser1182 = require('body-parser@1.18.0/package.json');

console.log(bodyParser.version);
console.log(bodyParser1181.version);
console.log(bodyParser1182.version);
```

Hope, this will serve your purpose.

Comment: Cool! It seems more elegant to solve the test problem. Do do you have any idea to count the coverage together?

Comment: I am not sure, what do you mean by "count the coverage together?"

Comment: Because test coverage is counted based on one test process, and when I use this way to structure the project, I need to run test process at each different version, the coverage cannot integrate together(ex: v1 test + v2 test...).

Comment: Can you please explain the format you think will work in your code. I have never done the test coverage :(

Comment: Just a note to those using scoped packages: you'll need to change the `mv` commands to: `mv ./node_modules/.tmp/${scope}/${dependency}@${version} ./node_modules/${dependency}@${version}`

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 separate projects (folders with package.json) and a shared folder:

1. A shared folder containing the test module (`my-test`). Export a function to run the test;
2. A client project importing `my-test` and dependency v1. Export a function that calls the test function in `my-test`.
3. A client project importing `my-test` and dependency v2. Export a function that calls the test function in `my-test`.
4. A master project that imports both client projects. Run each exported function.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to run them separately. Create a separate project folder for each dependency version. Ex. React10, React11, React12. Each will have its own `package.json`, specified for the correct version. When you run the `integration` and/or `versioned` tests, you'll run your standard unit tests across each version, but it may also be advisable to add any version specific unit tests to that folder.

Creating a `make` file would make your life easier when running your full testing suite. If you do this you can easily integrate this into CI.

Comment: This is one workable solution. But because just a little different of api change, I may duplicate some code in different version. Besides, it can't count code coverage together.

Comment: What code would you be duplicating? You should be running the same unit tests across each version. The idea for adding additional tests per version, would be to make it easier to remove them when a version is no longer supported and to allow you to test something that occurs only on that version.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions, you can try the approach described at [Testing multiple versions of a module dependency](https://jeffy.info/2020/10/01/testing-multiple-webpack-versions.html).

Here's an example of using this approach to test against multiple `webpack` versions:

```sh
npm install --save-dev module-alias
npm install --save-dev webpack-v4@npm:webpack@4.46.0
npm install --save-dev webpack-v5@npm:webpack@5.45.1
```

The [`module-alias` package](https://github.com/ilearnio/module-alias) handles the magic of switching between package versions while still supporting normal `require('webpack')` (or whatever your module is) calls.

The other `install`s will create two versions of your dependency, each with a distinct directory name within your local `node_modules/`.

Then, within your test code, you can set up the dependency alias via:

```js
const path = require('path');
require('module-alias').addAlias(
  'webpack',
  path.resolve('node_modules', 'webpack-v4'),
);

// require('webpack') will now pull in webpack-v4
```

You'd do the same thing for `'webpack-v5'` in a different test harness.

If any of your sub-dependencies have a hardcoded `require('webpack')` anywhere in their own code, this will ensure that they also pull in the correct `webpack` version.